# How to search and find and filter in Access vba

Tags: ms-access, search, filter, vba

In my Access database, I'm trying to perform a search and find routine which is quite complicated. Basically, I have 4 criteria to look for in these four tables: Date, Service, Code and Function.

With this information I go into a table, and search in a field and for one criteria. After I've found the rows which correspond to one of the 4 criteria, I save the value of the neighboring field for all the rows which matched correctly. After this, I wanted to save the values of all the neighboring fields as an array. Then repeating these steps, I was going to save all 4 searches as 4 individual arrays.

The relationships of my tables are as follows:

[image: Table Relationships]

I receive a "Demande" which is a request, and in that request are the four criteria: Date, Service, Code and Function.

In the table "Services_YES" I look for the **Service** that corresponds to the demand.

In the table "Pool_Personnel" I look for the **Fonction** that corresponds to the demand.

In the table "Days_Available" I look for both the **Date** and the **Code** (called Code_Horaire) which corresponds to the demand.

From there, I was hoping to record each Code_Personal for all of the results found, and then find which Code_Personal's matched in all of the 3 tables.

---

So My question:

How I can do a search and find function which creates an array of for all of the Code's which correspond to the criteria rows?

I have created psuedo code to help explain, and incase someone can *translate* this into real VBA:

```
While demandeTable.functionField.Value = poolpersonnelTable.Fonction1Field.Value
  get all poolpersonnelTable.codepersonalField.Value for all rows that match
  save fonctionArray = codepersonalField.Values
Loop
```

I'm very stuck on how to complete this 'filtering', and would strongly appreciate all help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you have a query where all tables are left-joined to the Demande table, and then just look in that query for results that have the Code_Personnel from each table being equal?

Comment: I'm bound to VBA because the query is to basic for what I need to do. I'm making a database which receives demands from an Outlook email frequently, and a macro which can find the right code quickly will work best I think. There process also become much, much more complicated.
Any ideas as to my psuedo code above?

Comment: @HansUp I posted another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183879/how-to-search-a-field-in-a-table-in-access), and will delete this one if it is answered well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using VBA is not the answer.

I ended up creating a Query, and using user-inputed text to fill in the variable parts of the query:

```
comboService = Chr(34) & Me.Combo8.Value & Chr(34)
txtDate = Chr(34) & Me.Text15.Value & Chr(34)
comboCodeHoraire = Chr(34) & Me.Combo17.Value & Chr(34)

"SELECT tblPoolPersonnel.LName, tblPoolPersonnel.FName, tblPoolPersonnel.[Tel Natel], tblPoolPersonnel.[Tel Home], tblPoolPersonnel.Email" & vbCrLf
"FROM ((tblPoolPersonnel INNER JOIN tblFonction ON tblPoolPersonnel.Code_Personal = tblFonction.Code_Personel) INNER JOIN tblDayAvailable ON tblPoolPersonnel.Code_Personal = tblDayAvailable.Code_Personal) INNER JOIN tblServiceYES ON tblPoolPersonnel.Code_Personal = tblServiceYES.Code_Personal" & vbCrLf
"WHERE (((tblServiceYES.Service)=" & comboService & ") AND " + _
                "((tblDayAvailable.Availability)=True) AND " + _
                "((tblDayAvailable.Date)=" & txtDate & ") AND " + _
                "((tblDayAvailable.CodeHoraire1)=" & comboCodeHoraire & "))"
```