# How to search a field in a table in Access

Tags: ms-access, find, vba

Using VBA, how can I search for a text string, for example **"CHIR"**, in a table called **"ServiceYES"**, in the field **"Service"**.

After that, I would like to save the neighboring field for all the rows that **"CHIR"** exists in the table **"ServicesYES"**. The **"ServiceYES"** table is below:

[image: ServiceYES table]

I basically, want to find all the **"CHIR"** in "Service" column and then save the names which are on the left of the CHIR, eg **"FRANKL_L"**, **"SANTIA_D"** as an array.

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by creating a `SELECT` query.

```
SELECT Code_Perso
FROM ServicesYES
WHERE Service = 'CHIR';
```

Use `SELECT DISTINCT Code_Perso` if you want only the unique values.

Add `ORDER BY Code_Perso` if you care to have them sorted alphabetically.

Once you have a satisfactory query, open a DAO recordset based on that query, and loop through the `Code_Perso` values it returns.

You don't need to load them directly into your final array.  It might be easier to add them to a comma-separated string.  Afterward you can use the `Split()` function (assuming you have Access version >= 2000) to create your array.

Here's sample code to get you started.  It's mostly standard boiler-plate, but it might actually work ... once you give it "yourquery".

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strItems As String
Dim varItems As Variant
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("yourquery", dbOpenSnapshot)
With rs
    Do While Not .EOF
        strItems = strItems & "," & !Code_Perso
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With
If Len(strItems) > 0 Then
    ' discard leading comma '
    strItems = Mid(strItems, 2)
    varItems = Split(strItems, ",")
Else
    MsgBox "Oops.  No matching rows found."
End If
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: create the query that returns the information you need. Whatever name you use to save it, put it into this line: `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("yourquery", dbOpenSnapshot)`

Comment: @Paolo, this is what I was talking about in your other question.  Left join all your tables in your query and look for the rows where the 3 IDs are equal will give you your final result set.  Without the query to do your work, VBA won't be able to find your results.

Answer (score 2):

I tested this and it seems to work.  This function will pull all records where ServiceYes='CHIR' and dump the Code_Person value into an array which it will return:

```
Function x() As String()
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset( _
         "Select * from ServiceYES where Service='CHIR'")

    Dim Arr() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    While rst.EOF = False
         ReDim Preserve Arr(i)
         Arr(i) = rst.Fields("Code_Person")
         i = i + 1
    rst.MoveNext
    Wend
    x = Arr
End Function
```

Sample Usage:

```
Debug.Print x()(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Paolo,

Here is something I threw together in a few minutes.  You can add it to the VBA editor in a module.  It uses a trick to get the RecordCount property to behave properly.  As for returing the array, you can update the function and create a calling routine.  If you need that bit of code, just post a comment.

Thanks!

```
Option Compare Database

Function QueryServiceYES()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim saveItems() As String

    Set db = CurrentDb

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Code_Perso, Service, Favorites " & _
                                "FROM ServiceYES " & _
                                "WHERE Service = 'CHIR'")

    'bug in recordset, MoveFirst, then MoveLast forces correct invalid "RecordCount"
    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst

    ReDim Preserve saveItems(rs.RecordCount) As String

    For i = 0 To rs.RecordCount - 1
        saveItems(i) = rs.Fields("Code_Perso")

        rs.MoveNext
    Next i

    'print them out
    For i = 0 To UBound(saveItems) - 1
        Debug.Print saveItems(i)
    Next i

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
End Function
```